# редактирование сообщения во время работы aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

делаю бота-chatGPT на aiogram 2 и у меня возникла проблема хочу сделать чтобы пока gpt думал бот изменял сообщение "подождите" добавляя и убирая "." к сообщению, у меня получилось это сделать на тестовом боте и всё работает так как я хочу, но стоит мне это добавить к коду gpt то он просто отправляет ответ и только после отправки изменяет сообщение.

рабочий код тест бота:

```py
state=None
async def large_func():
    global state
    count = 0
    for i in range(25):
        count += 1
        print(count)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    state=False
    return "Отлично!"

async def editing_func(message):
    loop_counter = 0
    while state:
        await message.edit_text(f"подождитеs{'.' * (loop_counter % 4)}\nㅤ")
        loop_counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await message.delete()

@dp.message_handler()
async def gpt_answer(message: types.Message):
    global state
    ed = await message.answer("подождите")
    state=True
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(editing_func(ed))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(large_func())

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
    result = await task2
    await message.answer(result)
```

не рабочий код:

```
state = None
#edeting message
async def edit_message(message):
    loop_counter = 0
    while state:
        await message.edit_text(f"ㅤ\n ⌛️ Ожидание ответа{'.' * (loop_counter % 4)}\nㅤ")
        loop_counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await message.delete()

#cahtGPT
async def ai(prompt):
    global state
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        temperature = 0.8,
        presence_penalty = 0.6,
        frequency_penalty = 0.6,
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ]
    )
    state = False
    return completion.choices[0].message.content



@dp.message_handler()
async def gpt_answer(message: types.Message):
    global state
    state = True
    editing_message = await message.answer("ㅤ\n ✅ Запрос отправлен!\nㅤ")
    try:
        task_edit_msg = asyncio.create_task(edit_message(editing_message))
        task_gpt = asyncio.create_task(ai(message.text))

        await asyncio.gather(task_edit_msg, task_gpt)
        result = await task_gpt
        await message.reply(result, parse_mode="Markdown")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await message.reply("❎Error!\nПроизошла ошибка перефразируйте своё сообщение или уменьшите количество слов")
```

Comment: await openai.Completion.acreate

Comment: @СергейШ что это?